# How do I specify the constructor definition of the inherited class?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I have a base class (header):

```
class BaseClass
{
    public:
        BaseClass(int); // note no default constructor.
}
```

and a class that derives it:

```
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass
{
    public:
        DerivedClass(void);
}

DerivedClass::DerivedClass (void) // note SPECIFICALLY no parameters.
{
    super (10); // equivalent of what I am trying to do in Java (I think)
}
```

How do I call the constructor of the inherited class in my derived class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Base class and derived class constructors calling in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764364/base-class-and-derived-class-constructors-calling-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this:

```
DerivedClass::DerivedClass (void) : BaseClass(10) 
{ }
```

NOTE: if you are unfamiliar with the syntax, look out for *member initialization list*.

Comment: Oh mother of a gun, I am so silly. I even read that at cplusplus.com and must have gone straight through me. Thanks. Link incase anyone is interested: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/

Answer (score 1):

```
class BaseClass 
{ 
    public: 
        BaseClass(int) {};
} ;
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass 
{ 
    public: 
        DerivedClass(void); 
}; 

DerivedClass::DerivedClass (void)
:BaseClass(10)
{ 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want:

```
DerivedClass(void):BaseClass(10) {
    //blah blah blah
}
```